# Transfer Windows Apache Configuration to OS X

Tags: mac, windows, apache

My normal development enviornment has always been in Windows, but I finally scrounged up the money for a nice Mac Book Pro. I've managed to get everything I need set up Git, My Working Copy Repo, Web App is building without issue but I have a very indepth Apache config that has a lot of vhosts and rewrites in it that allow me to access the inner pages of my web app on a dev enviornment which I didn't write myself (I find apache configs daunting).

If my version of apache on OSX matches the version on my Windows PC, can I just copy the config folder over and restart apache for it to work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably not blindly copy the entire Apache config directory. To start there will be several parts of the configuration that point to various files and folders that will be different.

The Mac stores the Apache config files in `/etc/apache2` so I suggest you have a look at the files in there and compare them to your existing Windows files so that you can make the required changes.

Then before you make any changes copy the entire `/etc/apache2` directory to somewhere safe so you can always roll back if you fail.

Comment: Thanks, I know this is best practices and figured the blind copy would not work but I figured I'd ask if there was an easy button before I started to go through all of my config files and transfer the relevant data to my mac install.